# Force http proxy use with module that already uses LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl

I would like to use a proxy server in conjunction with a third party SDK, but the SDK uses LWP::UserAgent internally and does not expose any proxy settings in its API.  I've tried setting an appropriate environment variable, but the module doesn't seem to recognize it.  Is there some way around this (without modifying the module itself)?

```
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://$proxyip:$proxyport';

my $s = NaServer->new ($filer, 1, 20);
$s->set_style(LOGIN);
$s->set_transport_type(HTTPS);
$s->set_server_type(FILER);
$s->set_port(443);
$s->set_admin_user($user, $pass);
$s->env_proxy;
```

[john0839@478261-apps ~]$ ./netapp_command_proxy.pl filerip myuser mypass
No definition for API env-proxy found at netapp-manageability-sdk-9.4/lib/perl/NetApp/OntapClusterAPI.pm line 109445.

Comment: Try to find if there is an lwp ua object like `$s->ua` or something like that in the source code, that's probably your only chance or see the documentation of how LWP::UA works with this component

Answer (score 1):

You've worked out that you need to call `env_proxy()` on the UserAgent object. But it seems that `NaServer` isn't a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent`, so you can't call the method on that class as you've tried in your example code.

Let's look at [the documentation for `LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) for clues. The [section for `new()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#new) has some interesting text.

> If `env_proxy` isn't provided, the `PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY` environment variable controls if "env_proxy" in LWP::UserAgent is called during initialization.

It looks to me like this feature is provided for exactly this situation. If you don't have access to the constructor for the object, you can use this environment variable to control the use of proxies. The code in the constructor looks like this:

```
my $env_proxy = exists $cnf{env_proxy} ? delete $cnf{env_proxy} : $ENV{PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY};
```

And, later,

```
$self->env_proxy if $env_proxy;
```

So the fix seems to be to add:

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_ENV_PROXY} = 1;
```

to the top of your code.

(N.B. I haven't had the time to test this.)

Comment: If that works, it would be awesome!  I'll test when I get back into the office.  Happy 4th, everybody!

Comment: @JohnHelms: 4th what?

Comment: Sorry, 4th of July.  American here.

Comment: Well, I have some bad news to report.  Setting that environment variable does not seem to force proxy use.  I'm simulating the firewall config with an ACL on the end point, and I get the same 503 error with & without the proxy variables:

Comment: @JohnHelms: Which version of LWP::UserAgent are you using? The code to automatically run `env_proxy()` was added in version 6.03. I got that info from the [Changes file](https://metacpan.org/source/OALDERS/libwww-perl-6.39/Changes).

Comment: Thanks for checking back, Dave.  Looking through the modules included in the SDK, I'm not even sure that it is using LWP::UserAgent.  The module that establishes the connection uses Socket, IO::Socket, and LWP::UserAgent, and it requires Net::SSLeay and IO::Select.  And it doesn't even seem to call UserAgent at all.  If I had to guess, I'd say that it's using IO::Socket to make the connection.  And IO::Socket has no mention of a proxy.  I think I might be SOL here.

Comment: Giving this a shot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610080/https-request-from-perl-over-proxy-with-iosocket-only